# Rename files named foobar(12345).txt to 12345.txt

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

All:

Quickly and succinctly, I have many many files named as such:

```
lorem(12312315).txt
    
ipsum(578938-12-315-13-416-4).txt
    
amet(ran-dom-guid).txt
```

And I want to rename them to what's inside the parentheses dot text, like so:

```
12312315.txt

578938-12-315-13-416-4.txt

randomguid.txt
```

I'm sure a mix of sed, awk, grep, etc will do it, but commenting out the parentheses from the shell is throwing me.  I cant come up with a string that will do it.

If anyone is kind enough to share a few thought cycles and help me, it would be a lovely Karma gesture!

Thanks for reading!
-Jim

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Thanks, Andy for the suggestion.  Point well taken, I will copy and paste the hot mess I've already tried for your viewing pleasure.  Just be nice lol, I'm a hack.

Comment: The key is that if you show us what you've worked on, we have a starting point to work from, and it's much easier for us. People are far more likely to help with existing code than to start from zero with "How do I do this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the responses!  I ended up using a mishmash of your suggestions and doing something else entirely, but I'm posting here for posterity...

The files all had one thing in common, the GUID contained in the filename was also always contained in line 2 of the accompanying file, so I yank lane two, strip out the things that are NOT the guid, and rename the file to that string, for any .xml file in the directory where the script is run.

as such:

```
for i in ./*xml
        do
                GUID=`cat "$i" | sed -n '2p' | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/<id>//g' | sed 's/<\/id>//'`
                echo File "|" $i "|" is "|" $GUID
        done
```

In the actual script, I do a MV instead of an ECHO and the files are renamed to the guid.

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future, and yes, I know it's wasteful to call sed three times.  If I were better with regular expressions, I'm sure I could get that down to one! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

find and mv can handle this, with a bash rematch to find your names;

```
#!/bin/bash
touch lorem\(12312315\).txt
touch ipsum\(578938-12-315-13-416-4\).txt
touch amet\(ran-dom-guid\).txt

pat=".*\((.*)\).txt"
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.txt" ); do
  if [[ $f =~ $pat ]]; then
    mv $f ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt
  fi
done
ls *.txt
```

Comment: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions

Comment: You just handed me a new tool!  I have not worked with BASH_REMATCH before, but that is some powerful stuff!  This community is awesome!  I'm a newb coder, but a network pro, and yall were nice enough to answer my dumb question.  Thanks, I got it from here.  I'll post what I used. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another flavor:

```
find . -type f -name \*\(\*\).txt -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c '
    for filename ; do 
      basename_core="${filename##*(}"
      basename_core="${basename_core%%)*}"
      mv "${filename}" "${basename_core}".txt
    done' dummy
```

Comment: I was considering using Xargs!  Thank you for the push in the right direction.  I thought maybe not use xargs since not all *nix distros in my enviro have that xargs but it's a great idea, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and shell);

```
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/mv '\''&'\'' '\''\1.txt'\''/p' *.txt
```

This will print out a list of move commands, after you have validated they are correct, pipe to shell:

```
sed -n 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/mv '\''&'\'' '\''\1.txt'\''/p' *.txt | sh
```

Comment: Thank you Potong!  Your quotes and commenting out skills are SO MUCH better than mine! :)  I will try this tonight after my shift and post results.

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop and Parameter Expansion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in *\(*\)*.txt; do
  temp=${f#*\(}
  value=${temp%\)*}

  case $value in
    *[!0-9-]*) value="${value//-}";;
  esac

  echo mv -v "$f" "$value.txt"
done
```

---

Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output, so `mv` can rename/move the files.